# How to configure NGINX properly for 2 different sites?

Tags: nginx, hosts, multiple-sites

I am  setting up new server, its all done. First site works without problems.

Path is:

```
/var/www/html
```

Second site is still not avaliable, but when i ping from command line it says its online.

Multiple directories should looks like this:

```
/var/www/html/1 

/var/www/html/2
```

or something else?

At this moment my default.conf from:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

looks like:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
root /var/www/html;
index index.html;
}
```

if i want put multiple sites i have to make this file looks like :

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example1.com;
root /var/www/html/1;
index index.html;
}
server {
listen 80;
server_name example2.com;
root /var/www/html/2;
index index.html;
}
```

or?

Any ideas?

Comment: So the server_name is the same? test.jasonrigden.com is in both configurations. So it'll only take one.

Comment: Did you try your conf example? What happened?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Honestly not, i am in job and trying to figure out if it will works. will check it later when i will be in home.

Comment: @flaixman nah, server_name is different. I changed this already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use a debian based system like debian or ubuntu.

I suggest to add a file like `example2.com.conf` to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and link it to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

For example

```
example2.com.conf:

server {
listen 80;
server_name example2.com;
root /var/www/html/2;
index index.html;
}
```

`ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example2.com.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
systemctl restart nginx`

Some more details are described on this page.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04#server-configuration